# PHP Calculate Exact number of hours minutes and seconds between two timestamps

Tags: php

I have two Timestamps 
2016-01-01 00:00:00 
2016-01-02 23:59:59

Using PHP how can I calculate the number of hours and minutes between the two times and get the result as a decimal with 2 places after the .

currently I have this:

```
    $Start = new DateTime($StartTime);
    $Finish = new DateTime ($FinishTime);
    $Interval = date_diff($Start,$Finish);
    $Hours = $Interval->format('%h.%i');
```

But the result is incorrect if the user starts the timer on Day 1 and finishes on day 2.

Comment: what are the values inside $StartTime and $FinishTime?

Comment: Values similar to that of the timestamps posted in the actual question. the $starttime is always before $finishtime as they are generated earlier and stored in mysql ready to be calculated at this point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could multiply the number of days by 24 to convert them to hours, then sum the hours and concatenate the minutes:

```
$start = new DateTime('2016-01-01 00:00:00');
$end = new DateTime('2016-01-02 23:59:59');
$interval = $end->diff($start);
$days = $interval->format('%d');
$hours = 24 * $days + $interval->format('%h');
echo $hours.':'.$interval->format('%i');
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$Hours = $Interval->format('%a.%h.%i');
```

Comment: That would give me the number of days as well. I need a sum of the hours. so I would get 33.25 or something instead of 1.12.1 the numbers i provided are incorrect but it does give a general idea of what i need.

Answer (score 0):

You could format the DateTime as a UNIX timestamp, and then simply subtract to get the total seconds, and format the output with gmdate().

```
$Start = new DateTime($StartTime);
$Finish = new DateTime ($FinishTime);
$Interval = $Start->format('U') - $Finish->format('U');
$Hours = gmdate("H:i:s", $Interval);
```